# React VR "jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision"

Tags: reactjs, react-360

I am using React VR Command Line Interface Version 0.3.0.  I downloaded the react-vr through a package manager.  When I run "npm start" command in my DemoApp folder, I got this error:

```
Loading dependency graph...
React packager ready.

jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: View
  Paths: /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-vr/Libraries/Components/View/View.vr.js collides with /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/View/View.js

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: LayoutPropTypes
  Paths: /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-vr/Libraries/StyleSheet/LayoutPropTypes.vr.js collides with /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/LayoutPropTypes.js

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: AnimatedImplementation
  Paths: /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-vr/Libraries/VRReactOverrides/AnimatedImplementation.vr.js collides with /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: NetworkOverlay
  Paths: /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-vr/Libraries/VRReactOverrides/NetworkOverlay.vr.js collides with /Users/akh/DemoApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Inspector/NetworkOverlay.js
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: The React VR team seems to be aware of this problem and have promised a fix in a upcoming release, see this Github issue https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/76.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling then reinstalling "react-native-router-flux" which worked for me.

> npm rm react-native-router-flux; npm install --save
>   react-native-router-flux

This was answered: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1803